# How do I add multiple numbers from input in python, using the while statement. (or any other statement)

Tags: python, function, if-statement, while-loop, project

Input an integer to add to the total or "Q" to quit
Enter an integer or "Q": 3
Enter an integer or "Q": 6
Enter an integer or "Q": 24
Enter an integer or "Q": 17
Enter an integer or "Q": 61
Enter an integer or "Q": nine
nine is invalid input
Enter an integer or "Q": q

Items
3
6
24
17
61

Total
 111

This was the example that was given. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

This should do it... Prints you beginning input line, and then add to totals from int, rejects other input except q and Q. Then it will return your final int

```
def add_to_total():
    print('Input an integer to add to the total or "Q" to quit')
    total=0
    while(True):
        newNum = input('Enter an integer or "Q": ')
        if(newNum=='q' or newNum=='Q'):
            return total
        try:
            total+=int(newNum)
        except:
            print('{} is invalid input'.format(newNum))
```